# verilog_code_compilation problem

Tags: verilog

In this program, I am trying to call a task which is in another file (or folder called trial) using

```
`include "trial.v"
```

During compilation, it shows the following error:

1. Cannot open `include file "trial.v"
2. near "else": syntax error, unexpected else

Is there any other method like `define to use this?
How to write`define path in top module?
Can you suggest correct code?
My program is

file named "cnt.v":

```
module sift_reg (dcsel, gsclk, s_in, sclk, blank);
input dcsel, gsclk, s_in, gs_enable, blank;
reg [11:0] counter_q;
wire dc_enable, gs_enable;
output sclk;
integer i;


`include "trial.v"

always @(posedge dcsel, posedge gsclk, s_in) begin
  if (dcsel) dc_enable <= '1';
  sclk <= '1';
  else
  sclk <='1'; 
  gs_enable <= '1';
end

initial counter_q = 12'b0;

/* gray scale counter */
always @(posedge gsclk, blank) begin
  if (blank)
    counter_q <= 12'b0;
  else
    counter_q <= counter_q + 1;
end

always @(posedge gsclk,dc_enable) begin
  for (i=0; i<48; i=i+1) begin
    if (dcsel==0) gs_shiftreg(s_in,sout);
  end
end

endmodule
```

another file "trial.v":

```
module shift_reg (input gsclk, sclk, dcsel, s_in, output sout);
input gsclk,sclk,dcsel;
input s_in;
reg  [191:0] temp;
output      sout;

`include "cnt.v"

task gs_shift_reg

  always @(posedge gsclk, posedge sclk) begin
    if(dcsel==0)
      temp <= {temp[190:0],s_in};
    else
      temp  <= 191'b0;
  end

  assign sout = temp;
endmodule
```

Comment: It can't find the file trial.v - it's that simple.

Comment: @pjc50 Maybe explain how to make sure it can find it?

Comment: While that problem is simple (you'll need to decide if that's another "file" or "folder" and set the path appropriately), `include is not the normal means of writing multi-file code.  IIRC you supply multiple source files to the compiler much as you would with a C compiler/link, though the details would depend on the verilog toolchain you are using.

Comment: You haven't said what it is you're trying to accomplish here, nor what tools you're using to compile the code. The source code is so full of syntax errors and apparent misconceptions that it's impossible to guess what your intent is. Overall, this qualifies, as "not a real question" as it stands.

Comment: This question might be better suited for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1):

To take one part of your code:

```
always @(posedge dcsel, posedge gsclk, s_in) begin
  if (dcsel) dc_enable <= '1';
  sclk <= '1';
  else
  sclk <='1'; 
  gs_enable <= '1';
end
```

This is how it should be written:

```
always @(posedge dcsel, posedge gsclk) // removed s_in since it's not used 
  begin
  if (dcsel) 
  begin // note begin and end added since there are two statements following "if"
      dc_enable <= 1'b1;      
      sclk <= 1'b1;
  end 
  else
  begin
      sclk <= 1'b1; 
      gs_enable <= 1'b1;
  end
end
```

You need the `begin` and `end` statements if you have more than one statement following the `if` or `else` statements, otherwise the compiler assumes only the line following is part of the statement.
Also, to assign a binary value, the syntax is n'bxxxxx, e.g. if you want to assign and 8 bit value to a register, use something like `8'b11110110;`, or `8'hF6;`

If you are getting problems with your include file, then either it has errors or the compiler can't find it.

There are other problems there (e.g. the `task` syntax is incorrect), it's not clear what you are trying to do overall - I'd pick up a decent book like "FPGA Prototyping by Verilog Examples" by Pong Chu and have a good read of that.